# Limiting HttpWebResponse stream reading speed

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I use this code to read a HttpWebResponse stream

```cs
Stream stm = httpResp.GetResponseStream();
Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 16];

AsyncCallback callback = null;
callback = ar =>
{
    int bytesRead = stm.EndRead(ar);
    fs.Write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
    if(bytesRead == 0)
        return;

    stm.BeginRead(buff, 0, buff.Length, callback, null);
};
stm.BeginRead(buff, 0, buff.Length, callback, null);
```

I want to limit the download rate. If I put a Thread.Sleep() inside the callback , it will keep the thread blocked, but it will not scale well with many streams. 
Is there any other way to achieve download limit and thread economy?

Comment: Are you sure that limits the download rate?

Comment: I think yes, if it pauses between chunks of data

Comment: You might want to test it. I think you'll be surprised.

Comment: I tested it and I saw some delay between the chunks of data. The total time of downloading the file was bigger (That's what I wanted). Are you offering some alternative?

Comment: I'm suggesting that the network stack will continue to receive the data and buffer it, so adding the delay in your code only controls how fast your program gets the data, not how fast it's downloaded from the server.

Comment: You mean if I ask (BeginRead) the 100 first bytes of 1 GB file the network will continue to receive 1 billion bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Putting a sleep inside the loop *might* limit the download rate. It depends on the underlying protocol implementation and the size of the internal network stream buffer.

On my system (Windows Server 2008, .NET 4.5), putting a sleep in the loop does limit the download speed.

It also depends on the setting of the [`request.AllowReadStreamBuffering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering.aspx) property. Documentation says that the default setting is `true`, but my testing shows that the default is `false` on my system. And in fact, trying to set it to `true` throws an exception.

However, it appears that the default is `true` for Silverlight. See [the Silverlight doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for that property. When set to `true`, the entire response is read and buffered before the response is ready to be read.

Assuming that limiting the rate of read requests will limit the download rate (which seems reasonable, provided you disable read stream buffering), I don't see a good way to do it with `BeginRead`/`EndRead`. As you point out, putting a `Thread.Sleep` in there isn't going to scale well.

With .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0, you should consider using `GetResponseAsync` to get the response, and `ReadAsync` when reading the response stream. With .NET 4.0, you can create a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235678.aspx) to do the reading. Either of those will let you use [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096.aspx) to create your delays. This will have the same effect as `Thread.Sleep` in controlling the download speed, but will not block the thread.

Unfortunately, I don't have an example for you.